Upon upgrade to 24.04 - Spacebar preview stopped working
I guess it's all in the title, the spacebar preview feature, that was rather useful to me, doesn't work. I've checked if Sushi is installed, and apparently I have the latest version already setup, not sure how I can get it to work now...

Needs details. What space bar preview?

Sorry I should have specified better... in version 20 if you go on a directory and select a file, you could press the spacebar and a window would pop up showing a "preview" of the file without opening the actual application needed to run it. For example a PDF would show a preview of the file without having the actual application to see pdf to run. I hope I explained better...

version 20 would be a version of Ubuntu Core. Not how version numbers work in Ubuntu. Accurate info is always needed.

Sorry again! 20.04 LTS, that was the version I was coming from. Now I have 22.04 LTS installed, the computer did an upgrade from 20.04, it was not a clean install from scratch.
